# DirectX11 Execution Warning #355

Tags: c++, directx, warnings

When I run my DirectX11 project, I get spammed in my output window every time the `ID3D10Device::DrawIndexed` is called with this warning

> D3D11: WARNING: ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed: Input vertex slot 0
>   has stride 48 which is less than the minimum stride logically expected
>   from the current Input Layout (56 bytes). This is OK, as hardware is
>   perfectly capable of reading overlapping data. However the developer
>   probably did not intend to make use of this behavior.  [ EXECUTION
>   WARNING #355: DEVICE_DRAW_VERTEX_BUFFER_STRIDE_TOO_SMALL ]

This is how I'm currently calling the function

> pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed( this->vertexBuffer.indices.size() * 3,
>   0, 0 );

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong that is causing this warning. If someone could shed some light on the issue I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that your input layout has a different total byte size than the stride you have set when setting the vertex buffer.

To fix the problem you need to ensure that that the input layer set via IASetInputLayout() has the same stride as the one set when you call IASetVertexBuffers().

Comment: Yub, that was it. I miss counted. Thank you very much.